# How do I register a onblur hook for a select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I have this, a multi select tag, which calls the function every time something is selected/deselected. But I want the function to be called when a user clicks out of the dropdown select_tag, any ideas?

`<%= select_tag ... :onchange => 'handleChange()' %>`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways.

The best way to accomplish this is with some unobtrusive JavaScript. Add an event listener like this:

```
  # <%= select_tag 'state' ... ' %> =>

  <select name="state" id="state" multiple>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
  </select>
  
  <script>
    let element = document.getElementById('state');
    element.addEventListener('blur', event => console.log("blur, baby, blur"));
  </script>
```

If you prefer to use jQuery and it's already imported, you can use its event handlers. The jQuery version would go something like this:

```
$(document).on('blur', '#state', event => console.log('blur, baby, blur'));
```

Note that passing the event to your function is optional. I'm adding the event handler directly to the document which means that it would work even if the select element is dynamically added to the page after page load.

You can alternatively use this more classic jQuery approach if you are not dynamically loading the element.

```
$('#element-id').on('blur', function() {
  // do stuff
}
```